# ReferenceError with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I'm using SystemJS as a module system to compile my TypeScript files but whenever I load the page in browser (via [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)) I get following error:

```
ReferenceError: Sensor is not defined
    at (index):17
    at <anonymous>
```

This is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Sensor</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="textField"/> 
    <p id="text"></p>

    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script>
        SystemJS.import('dist/index.js').then( function() {
            var textField = new Sensor(document.getElementById('textField')).setName('textField');
        }).catch(function(err) { console.log(err); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "dist/index.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "./src/sensor.ts",
        "./src/signal.ts",
        "./src/signal_receiver.ts"
    ]
}
```

I checked output file and it looks like `Sensor` **is** defined:

```
System.register("sensor", ["signal", "signal_receiver"], function (exports_3, context_3) {
    ...
    exports_3("Sensor", Sensor);
```

**Edit:** I checked now and none of the functions were defined when I tried to call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing two problems with your code. One is that you are using a bundle, but your code ignores that. Second is that you are not getting `Sensor` class from your module but instead you're getting it from the global space.

In the code generated by `tsc`, the call for `System.register` has `"sensor"` for the first argument, which means that you are dealing with a bundle. This kind of call hardcodes the module name, and the module name here is `"sensor"`. SystemJS bundles can be loaded with a `script` element so you could just add this after you load SystemJS:

```
<script src="dist/index.js"></script>
```

This will load the whole bundle and make all modules in it available for use.

Then the generated code for your module exports the `Sensor` class as the `Sensor` field on your module. (That's what the code `exports_3("Sensor", Sensor)` does.) So you need to get it from the module when you use it. So the code should be:

```
SystemJS.import('sensor').then(function(sensor) {
  var textField = new sensor.Sensor(document.getElementById('textField')).setName('textField');
}).catch(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

In this code, I'm asking SystemJS to load the module named `"sensor"` which is the same name used by `System.register`, and I've added `sensor` to the argument list of the callback passed to `.then` and refer to the class as `sensor.Sensor`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation Louis; I'm fairly new to whole this thing about modules but now I understand it much better!